# How to override jna.tmpdir and java.io.tmpdir properties in testcontainers?

Tags: testcontainers

TestContainers have Native.java class, where it gets JNA props from "jna.tmpdir" key. How to override value of that key? like:

```
jna.tmpdir=/data/builds/compose-tmp 
java.io.tmpdir=/data/builds/compose-tmp
```

Part of code where it gets jna prop:

```
package com.sun.jna;

public final class Native implements Version {

...

   static File getTempDir() throws IOException {
       File jnatmp;
       String prop = System.getProperty("jna.tmpdir");
       if (prop != null) {
           jnatmp = new File(prop);
           jnatmp.mkdirs();
       }
}
```

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to a similar question. I'm facing issues with AppLocker and JNA temp files generated by a Java Application

Comment: In our Windows server, the Java App generates the JNA DLL file into the current user's "temp" folder which is blocked by the AppLocker configuration. If possible, do refer my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772475/windows-applocker-path-wildcards-for-files-and-folders/74781754?noredirect=1#comment131990919_74781754